# I need some sort of rigid body collision detection engine for Android

Tags: java, android, math, collision

I have tried to make my own to work on Android, but I have failed. What I mean with rigid body collision detection is that basically there is a wall and as soon as the player touches the wall, it cannot go through. I have tried to use Box2D, Emini Engine, PPhys2D, Phys2D, and either they dont have enough tutorials or they are really complicated. I wrote this to use with my normal Java games:

```
//package
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class DCDE {
int plx, ply, obx, oby, obw, obh, plw, plh;
Rectangle north;
Rectangle east;
Rectangle south;
Rectangle west;
boolean debug=true;
public void debug(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    if(debug)
    {
        if(!(north==null)&&!(east==null)&&!(south==null)&&!(west==null)){
            g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g2.draw(north);
            g2.draw(east);
            g2.draw(south);
            g2.draw(west);
            g2.fill(north);
            g2.fill(east);
            g2.fill(south);
            g2.fill(west);
        }
    }
}
public void detect(int plxj, int plyj, int obxj, int obyj, int obwj, int obhj, int plwj, int plhj)
{
    plx=plxj;
    ply=plyj;
    obx=obxj;
    oby=obyj;
    obw=obwj;
    obh=obhj;
    plw=plwj;
    plh=plhj;
    Rectangle playr = new Rectangle(plx, ply, plw, plh);
    Rectangle objr = new Rectangle(obx, oby, obw, obh);
    north = new Rectangle((obx), (oby-1), obw, 1);
    east = new Rectangle((obx+obw), (oby), 1, obh);
    south = new Rectangle((obx), (oby+obh)+1, obw, 1);
    west = new Rectangle((obx-1), oby, 1, obh);
    if(playr.intersects(north)){
        ply=(oby-plh-1);
        if(debug)System.out.println("NORTH");
    }
    if(playr.intersects(east)){
        plx=(obx+obw+1);
        if(debug)System.out.println("EAST");
    }
    if(playr.intersects(south)){
        ply=(oby+obh+1);
        if(debug)System.out.println("SOUTH");
    }
    if(playr.intersects(west)){
        plx=(obx-plw-1);
        if(debug)System.out.println("WEST");
    }
}
}
```

This worked fine on the computer-java games i had made, but now I need something like the above but for android. So is there some sort of engine JUST made for collision detection and not the whole gravity stuff, or is there some easy maths way I could use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can still use your rectangles and `intersect()` in Android, just switch to `android.graphics.Rect` and convert the width and height members to left and bottom. Or is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: I have tried that and it runs really slow. Is there some other way to do it?

Comment: You're probably not going to get any faster than just comparing integers. Did you try it on a real device? I ask because everything is crazy slow on the emulator.

Comment: I tried it on my Xperia Play (R800i)

Comment: @stevehb Would the DCDE way (above, and optimised for android) be efficient and the way to go? Would you do it that way?

Comment: I don't know what DCDE is, but if all I needed was AABB testing (rects without rotation), then I'd probably start by testing whether the player and object rects `intersect()`, and if they do, then I'd test manually for a top/bottom/left/right collision. Pseudocode for manual testing top/bottom collision looks like: `if(player.left is between obj.right and obj.left OR player.right is between obj.left and obj.right) then if(player.top is between obj.top and obj.bottom) then 'collision top' else if(player.bottom is between obj.top and obj.bottom) then 'collision bottom'`

Comment: @stevehb Sorry, I call the above code DCDE (Dynamic Collision Detection Engine). I have now adapted it for Android and have called it ACDE (Android Collision Detection Engine). However, there is a little glitch where the player just spazzes out sometimes. The code can be found here: http://cl.ly/Bo3F Do you know why it glitches? I set the position one pixel further or nearer to prevent getting stuck.

Comment: I think ill ask a new question about the jerkiness of my ACDE

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a graphics engine that already works on android, like [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) or [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/blog/). I'm they've already have thing kind of stuff built in along with a bunch of other nice things.

Comment: I am more the kind of person that actually understands what goes on behind the scenes.

Comment: +1 for AndEngine. You wont escape having to learn a bit about Box2d but what you want to do is covered in many of their examples.